# How to make some of the picture static, and the rest dynamic

Tags: opengl

I am new here, just as I am new to OpenGL. I am yet to understand how it really works but I need something done so here's my question. I've got this code. How can i make a static coordinate system in here? I mean i want the system to be drawn in the center of a figure, and when I rotate the figure, the system shouldn't move at all. I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

Well...i was having problems with putthing my whole source in here, so i decided to upload it on some hosting site:
[My sourcecode here](http://wklejto.pl/204073)

@DOWN (i cant replay yet bcos i am new here :) )

I have managed to come up with something like this. But it doesn't look too good ;/ I mean the figure is always in the front and i don't have any idea how to make it hide behind the axis so that it look real when it rotates.

[My new code](http://wklejto.pl/204073)

How to use these in my code? I guess it should solve my problem:

```
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it sounds like you want to rotate "in place", in which case you need to issue your rotate commands before your translate and scale commands (openGL performs a so-called 'left-multiply' of matrices so it can seem like you are specifying multiplications in the opposite order that you would like them to happen...)

this is a good chapter from the famous RED BOOK on transformations:

http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter03.html#name2

Comment: I tried to use the thing you gave me and it works, but it doesnt look so good. Is there any way to make the figure hide behind the axises while rotating? I mean that the part that shouldnt be seen would be behind the axis. This way it would look more real.

Comment: it sounds like you need to perform "hidden surface removal"... z-buffering is a famous algorithm for this from the 1970s... luckily it is built into the GL.  see this chapter of the RED BOOK: http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter05.html#name1  the three statements will "CREATE ZBUFFER", "ENABLE ZBUFFER", and "CLEAR ZBUFFER"...

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! It works perfectly now. Btw, I wonder if you could tell me if there is any OpenGL for newbies tutorial or book?

Comment: One more thing, If i wanted to move my camera around static object: I mean now I want the objects ( all of them) not to move, but for example by holding right mouse button rotate the camera every way around my objects. Is there something that I can easily use to get that effect?

Comment: hmm maybe use gluLookAt() and setup your mouse callback to change its values... for newbie book, i like the second edition of the RED BOOK (1997) since it comes from a time when openGL only had 200 or so functions instead of 2000 today (or some nutso number)... that is the book i linked you to twice.  also check out the sample programs that came with the old GLUT distribution, they still run today and are small enough to easily learn from: http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/code/samples/glut_examples/examples/examples.html  (check out DINOSPIN especially)

Comment: Ok, I get how to use right mouse button to change the gluLookAt coordinates, but how should i calculate them, any suggestions? I mean i can't just put raw mouse x,y into the gluLookAt state, it has to be somehow calculated to give a nice angle of looking. As I said i am still a newbie and it causes me much trouble :) Thank you for helping me anyway.

Comment: you want to search on 'arcball' or 'virtual trackball'... there is a demo in that GLUT page i linked... also read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21603412/algorithm-3d-orbiting-camera-control-with-mouse-drag/21646259#21646259

Comment: Thank you for everything :)

Comment: I was also wondering. Is there any way to divide the window? I mean for example on the top I would use the OpenGL rendering part, and on the bottom for example ordinary WinAPI part. Bcos I need to create some buttons and inputs and as far as I have read it's quite troublesome since I have to create my own controlls from the very beginning.

Comment: that i do not know!  i don't work with windows, sorry

Comment: I have another question :) 

http://wklejto.pl/204196

This function will draw a coordinate system. How can i get the (x,y) of each end of arrow? I want to add "X" ,"Y" , "Z" there. I copy-pasted this code and i can't really understand how it works.

Comment: things like printing text aren't included in openGL...  you are going to need something like GLUT (but even that will print in 2D)

Comment: I am using GLUT in my project. I have already written functions to print text on screen in 2d on the specific coordinates. I just dont know how to get the X,Y of end of each axis to put the text there.

Comment: not sure what you mean by "get the X, Y of end of each axis", maybe you can post a new question about it?

Comment: Sure :) here's link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24236099/how-to-get-coordinates-of-the-end-of-each-axis-drawn-by-my-function-glut